# MvvmCross FilePlugin save files to SD card

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

We use beautiful MvvmCross framework in our app and we also utilize the FilePlugin to work with filesystem in a cross-platform way.

By default the FilePlugin stores data in some default location, like `/data/data/<appname>` in Android.
But what if I want to store big files, like video or 3D models? In iOS you store everything in app folder, but in Android you'll likely want to store files on SD card.

What solution would you recommend for this usecase?
I mean, should I inherit the FilePlugin and override app root directory for Android somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hade the same problem, and solved it by creating my own implementation of IMvxFileStore. My implementation allows me to specify an absolute path.

```
internal class CustomMvxAndroidFileStore : MvxFileStore
{
    private Context _context;

    private Context Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
            {
                _context = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidGlobals>().ApplicationContext;
            }
            return _context;
        }
    }

    protected override string FullPath(string path)
    {
        if (PathIsAbsolute(path)) return path;

        return Path.Combine(Context.FilesDir.Path, path);
    }

    private bool PathIsAbsolute(string path)
    {
        return path.StartsWith("/");
    }
}
```

And then inject it during Setup of the app:

```
Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxFileStore, CustomMvxAndroidFileStore>();
```

This worked fine for me.

Comment: Your solution is fine, except you don't even need PathIsAbsolute check. Here is excerpt from Path.Combine documentation: ```Return Value
Type: System.String
The combined paths. If one of the specified paths is a zero-length string, this method returns the other path. If path2 contains an absolute path, this method returns path2.```